# Safari not working with notification center

Tags: mac, macos, macbook-pro

I have a new macbook pro with mountain lion. I want to use the notification center for my Facebook/gmail, but when I'm logged into both facebook and gmail, I never get alerts.I have safari available in my notification center, but it won't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

When you go to Gmail in Safari 6, you should see this at the top:

[image]

That should enable alerts in Notification Center. You could also set up your Gmail in Mail.app.

On Apple's website for [Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#facebook), it says:

> Facebook integration coming this fall.

So it may be a few weeks still before you can use Facebook with Notification Center.

Comment: If you won't see the desktop notifications banner you could go to settings to enable them.